# fop xsl display superscript ordinal

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

How to display superscript ordinal in xsl, i cant find any thing related on internet.

I want to display dates 1, 2, 3, 4 as :

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#baseline-shift

Comment: There is an 'ordinal' font feature in OpenType for doing that, but FOP doesn't do OpenType font features (and the font has to support the feature as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<fo:inline baseline-shift="33%" font-size="58.3%">
  <!-- here your st, nd, rd or th -->
</fo:inline>
```

[See here why 58.3% for @font-size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript)